# WP behind haproxy weirdness

Tags: login

I have set up WP in containers on some Fedora 37 virtual machines. I have set up an haproxy virtual machine as a front-end.

I set up haproxy and it's definitely doing round-robin between the different WP containers. I set the haproxy machine to resolve to my hostname, http://wp.example.com/. I can browse the content on my WP site, but every time I try to log in at http://wp.example.com/wp-admin, it just redirects me to log in again. After lots of searching, I figured out that if I change the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in /wp-admin/options-general.php to be http://192.168.1.10 (the IP address of the load balancer) instead of http://wp.example.com, it works. I can log into the /wp-admin interface.

But then, any time anyone clicks on a link, it opens up http://192.168.1.10 instead of http://wp.example.com, which I think looks kind of silly.

Why does it fail logging in to a load balanced WP instance if you use the hostname instead of the IP address? Is there a way around this?